# JQUERY : Copy 1st input to 2nd input (Array Inputs)

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have and two array inputs. I want them to be equal on key up event.
The problem is I cannot get each 1st input value to be equal on each 2nd input.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YBQKz/6/)** (This fiddle only copies the first input)

Jquery I have used. (

> Which only works for mgr[[1](http://jsfiddle.net/YBQKz/6/)] to gm[[1](http://jsfiddle.net/YBQKz/6/)]. but fails to copy mgr[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od0uD.png)] to gm[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od0uD.png)] or mgr[3](http://jsfiddle.net/YBQKz/7/) to gm[3](http://jsfiddle.net/YBQKz/7/)
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     $("#mgr").keyup(function(){
>       $('#gm').val($('#mgr').val());
>     });
> ```
>
> });

I have also tried this jquery. 
But its copies 1st input value to all 2nd input
**[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YBQKz/7/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('input[name="mgr[]"]').keyup(function(){
   var val = 0;
   $('input[name="mgr[]"]').each(function() {
                val += Number($(this).val());
            });

   $('input[name="gm[]"]').each(function() {
                $(this).val(val);
            });
});

});
```

What I want

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Your jsFiddle seems to be working, what's the problem? The input is put into the correct `p` element, it's just doesn't look that way b/c `p` is a block element so they're stacked on top of each other, making it look like only the first p element is receiving the input.

Comment: It only copies the value of mgr[1] to gm[1] . but fails to copy the value of mgr[2] to gm[2] or mgr[3] to gm[3]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/47pZS/3/ It's an html formatting issue, your logic is correct.

Comment: what if I have the same ID for each <p> and <input> ? The problem here is Im working with input arrays.

Comment: ID's should be unique. Otherwise you'll get unintended behavior.

Comment: I have while loop which echos inputs. (those two inputs). thats why I put them in an array. I hope you understand.

Comment: I don't really understand. Whats the problem with the second jsFiddle

Comment: wait let me correct my fiddle links

Comment: Please kindly check my updated fiddle links. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost you should stop using the same ID's in html, FOREVER. Your code will never work the way it's supposed to, you're going against convention.

I've managed to correct your code to work in an array like manner, where the 2nd input is found through the 1st input's index.

http://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/YBQKz/8/

```
$('input[name="mgr[]"]').keyup(function(){
   var index = $(this).index('input[name="mgr[]"]')
   $('input[name="gm[]"]').eq(index).val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: OMG! this is exactly what I have wanted. I am very sorry if I have the same ID's. Its just  that its on LOOP. But will take note your advice.

Answer (score 1):

As per your HTML structure this code will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type=text]").on("input", function() {
    if($(this).index() / 2 != 0 || $(this).index() == 0) {
      $(this).next().val($(this).val());
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/YBQKz/9/)

Answer (score 0):

First short explication about the code that you are follow.
In Jquery you have selectors for get the elements in the DOM, those selectors can be "." for class or  "#", for id attribute.

So in the example the jquery function is saying if you click on a element with "js-key-up" class take the value in id attribute and then search an element with the id atribute with this form *'#' + id + '-in-document'*.
In your case can be something like this code.

```
<input class="mgr" id="1">
<input class="mgr" id="2">
<input class="mgr" id="3">

<input  id="gm1">
<input  id="gm2">
<input  id="gm3">

$('.mgr').keyup(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#gm' + id').html($(this).val());
});
```

I hope it helps. Good luck!